# How can I repair a fiberglass ladder?

Tags: repair, tools

I have a 10 ft fiberglass step ladder that was damaged when someone used it on unstable ground.  This ended up ripping one of the rivets on the middle locking brace out of the fiberglass.  Anyone have any recommendations?

I was thinking that I could clean up the fiberglass and make a repair with the fiberglass mat/cloth/resin they sell at auto parts stores.

I could also just try to sandwich the damaged area between two pieces of steel bolted together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixing the fiberglass is not a good idea. The point where the brace attaches to the ladder is frequently stressed in multiple directions and any fiberglass repair you do is likely to not hold up.

Fixing it with 2 steel plates is a better idea. If the damage to the fiberglass is small and isolated to just one face, then I recommend the steel be at least 6 inches long and as wide as possible. Use at least 6 bolts, if not 8.

However, if the damage extends past the face and on to the front or back face then I don't think repairing it is a safe idea.

Comment: Ok, sounds like steel is the way to go.  Luckily the damage is only on one face, basically a hole about the size of dime where the rivet just ripped through the fiberglass.